# How to have a key (string) not freed for global and mutable HashTable in a DLL with Rust?

Tags: rust, memory, dll, hashtable, global

I'm trying to implement a cross-platform DLL/SharedObject written in Rust. I have a global and mutable HashTable initialized in this library. When i add a key and value in this HashTable, the key (a `&'static str`) is freed, reset with `\0` characters and reassigned to another use. I don't understand this behaviour because i declare the variable as `&'static str`, so Rust should not free the memory until the process finishes. Can you explain the behavior to me ? Do you know the right way to solve the problem ?

I don't have this behaviour in executable, only in DLL.

Code Rust DLL/SharedObject:

```rust
use std::{sync::Mutex, collections::HashMap};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Color {
    Red,
}

impl Color {
    fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        match *self {
            Color::Red    => 1,
        }
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref STATE_OK: State = {
        State {
            name: String::from("OK"),
            color: Color::Green,
            character: "+".to_string(),
        }
    };
    static ref STATES: Mutex<HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn _State + Send>>> = {
        let _states: HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn _State + Send>> = HashMap::from(
            [
                (
                    "OK",
                    Box::new(STATE_OK.clone()) as Box<dyn _State + Send>
                )
            ]
        );
        Mutex::new(_states)
    };
}

fn rust_from_c_string (string_c: *const u8) -> &'static str {
    let length = strlen(string_c);
    let slice = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(string_c, length) };
    std::str::from_utf8(slice).unwrap()
}

fn strlen(string_c: *const u8) -> usize {
    let mut length = 0;
    unsafe {
        while *string_c.add(length) != 0 {
            length += 1;
        }
    }
    length
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn add_state (key_: *const u8, character_: *const u8, color_: *const u8) {
    let key: &'static str = rust_from_c_string(key_);
    let color = rust_from_c_string(color_);
    let character = rust_from_c_string(character_);

    let mut _states = STATES.lock().unwrap();
    _states.insert(
        key,
        Box::new(State {
            name: String::from(key),
            color: match color {
                "red"    => Color::Red,
            },
            character: String::from(character),
        }) as Box<dyn _State + Send>
    );
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn messagef (text_: *const u8, state_: *const u8) {
    let text = rust_from_c_string(text_);
    let state = rust_from_c_string(state_);
    let to_print: String;
    let _states = STATES.lock().unwrap();
    let state = _states.get(&*state.unwrap_or("OK").to_string()).unwrap();
    print!("{}", to_print);
    let _ = stdout().flush();
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn print_all_state () {
    DEFAULT_STATE.lock().unwrap().print("not found");

    let _states = STATES.lock().unwrap();

    for (key, state) in _states.iter() {
        state.print(key);
    }
}
```

Call it from python:

```py
from ctypes import c_char_p, c_ubyte, c_ushort, pointer
from os.path import join, dirname, exists
from os import name, getcwd

if name == "nt":
    from ctypes import windll as sysdll

    filename = "TerminalMessages.dll"
else:
    from ctypes import cdll as sysdll

    filename = "libTerminalMessages.so"

filenames = (join(dirname(__file__), filename), join(getcwd(), filename))
for filename in filenames:
    if exists(filename):
        break
else:
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Library {filename!r} is missing")

lib = sysdll.LoadLibrary(filename)

lib.print_all_state()

lib.add_state(
    c_char_p("TEST".encode()),
    c_char_p("T".encode()),
    c_char_p("red".lower().encode()),
)

lib.messagef(
    c_char_p("test".encode()),
    c_char_p("TEST".encode()),
)

lib.print_all_state()
```

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/mauricelambert/TerminalMessages).

I take a screenshot where:

1. i add 2 keys and values named `TEST` and `TEST2`
2. i list all keys and values, `TEST` and `TEST2` are present with the good key value
3. i use my library and the HashTable with initialized keys, this is working good
4. i list all keys and values, `TEST2` value is present with key `\0\0\0\0\0` (5 `\0` characters) and `TEST` value is present with key `Ques` (a part of `Question` word used in precedent message)
5. i use my library and the HashTable with `TEST`, `TEST2` and initialized keys. `TEST`, `TEST2` are not found but initialized keys are found.

[image: ScreenShot].

Comment: Code should be provided in the question itself, not behind a link. But the code in the link you shared looks like a lot. Please reduce it to the minimum required to exhibit the behavior. See [How to create a MRE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your `rust_from_c_string` looks particularly suspicious; you should show that and how you call it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I add a minimum required code to exhibit the behavior. The `rust_from_c_string` transform a `*const u8` to `&'static str`. It's working good for multiples strings, do you think the declaration of the string cause this bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incorrectly handling the Python strings: `c_char_p("TEST".encode())` does not have a `'static` lifetime.

> I don't understand this behaviour because i declare the variable as `&'static str`, so Rust should not free the memory until the process finishes.

Rust is not in control of the memory passed to it from a different language, and annotating it as `'static` doesn't change anything. Rust's lifetimes are *descriptive* and not *prescriptive* and you are describing the lifetime incorrectly. Part of the safety requirements of `from_raw_parts` is that the deduced lifetime is not longer than the underlying object is alive. If you did guarantee the Python string would persist indefinitely then that is one thing, but you aren't.

Rust is not free-ing the memory, but Python is, and the memory that was used for the string will be reclaimed by the GC and reused (or apparently in this case cleared with zeros) while Rust still has a pointer to where it was.

You would have to make that guarantee yourself by creating an *owned* `String` and then `leak()`-ing it to make a true `&'static str`. Something like this:

```
fn rust_from_c_string (string_c: *const u8) -> &'static str {
    let length = strlen(string_c);
    let slice = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(string_c, length) };
    let str_r = std::str::from_utf8(slice).unwrap();
    let string_r = str_r.to_owned();
    String::leak(string_r)
}
```

Although at that point you should just make your `HashMap` store `String`s from the start (or at least `Cow<str, 'static>`) to avoid leaking if your API needs to clear the data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is working good. I thought Rust generated its own string in its own buffer with the function `std::str::from_utf8`. There is a little error in your code, this is the `to_owned()` method and not `into_owned()`. Could you edit your code so I can validate your answer ?